# Spring boot validation doesn't work

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have Spring boot application and I can't show error message to user. Object without that data is not saved in the database and that is OK. But showing error message is the problem. When I debug i get errors size = 0

This is my model:

```
 @Size(min = 1, message = "Address is invalid.")
 @NotNull
 @Column
 private String address;
```

Controller

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
  consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
  public String createNewBusiness(@Valid @ModelAttribute("business") 
  Business business, BindingResult result, Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("userEmail", getUserEmail());
   logger.info("/business/create:" + business.toString());
  LocationResponse locationResponse = geoService.getCoords(business.getAddress());

if(locationResponse.getStatus().equals("OK")) {
    business.setLatitude(locationResponse.getResults().get(0).getGeometry().getLocation().getLat());
    business.setLongitude(locationResponse.getResults().get(0).getGeometry().getLocation().getLng());
    business.setUserId(getUserId());

    businessService.createNew(business);

    model.addAttribute("business", business);

}else{
    business.setAddress(null);
    model.addAttribute("business", business);

}

if(result.hasErrors()){
    List<FieldError> errors = result.getFieldErrors();
    for (FieldError error : errors ) {
        System.out.println (error.getObjectName() + " - " + error.getDefaultMessage());
    }
    return "newBusiness";
}

return "business";
```

}

And Thymeleaf

```
<div class="input-field left m-0 w-100">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker prefix grey-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <input placeholder="Address" id="inputAddress" name="address" type="text" class="validate my-0" th:required="true">
                        <label th:errors="*{address}" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('address')}" >Invalid address </label>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Does my solution work for you? Please let me know about it (later).

Comment: I edited controller,  but still, error message doesn't show

Comment: You´re validating `buisness` but you want the `adress` to be valid and enter it on UI. Is this field part of the `buisness`-Entity?

Comment: Yes, field address is part of buisness.

Comment: Try to use the field ID on UI for showing up the message. So you shopuld use `inputAddress` instead of `adress` on `.hasErrors()`.
Last think I would expect is that you need to use the field-id...

Comment: Been there, done that. But it doesn't work. I also tried ${#fields.errors('*')}" but the result is the same...

Comment: Use `th:field="*{adress}"` on the inputField - instead of `id` and `name`, or let them, but you need to define it for th framework.

Comment: I spent whole day on that and I'm still stuck. I still can't show error. In debug it shows error size 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to throw a custom validation error (for example, if you're validating a field by something other than the annotation validators in your model), you can do that through `BindingResult#rejectValue()` method.
For example:

```
if (business.getEmail()  == null || business.getEmail().length() == 0) {
    result.rejectValue("email", "email.missing", "Must enter email");
}
```

Obviously email field is just an example, as you would need that email field on your thymeleaf resource as well as the error field.

More on this topic at
https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#rejectValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

You need to  use `@Valid` and on some also `@ModelAttribute` for the parameter of `createNewBusiness()` - depending on your parameters and stuff.

Also you need to add `th:field="*{adress}"` to your inputfield because it´s the ID of this inputfield in the framework.

---

So in you case the method header will look like this:

```
public String createNewBusiness(@ModelAttribute Business business,
    @Valid Model model, BindingResult result) {
    // ...
}
```